# TLS/SSL error in between of web service checks

Tags: powershell, ssl

I have a powershell script to check a webserver page availability and task runs for every 5mins.

But I am getting TLS/SSL request is aborted error for every 3-4 hour once.

I have used the below one in my code and it's works fine.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I had setup timeout secs(100) for invoking my web request but it doesn't seem to work this way.

Someone can help me why it's giving TLS/SSL errors all of a sudden? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting issue. It could be many issues:

1. This could be an issue with the server; Perhaps the server is dropping requests or has some internal handling issues.
2. The request may be timing out before it has a chance to receive a response.
3. There could be network errors unrelated to your script or the target server.

I wrap your web request method in a try-catch, if it catches than it tries again, up to a certain specified amount of times. If this does not fix it, there is a chance that the problem lies with the server and not your script.

Comment: Hi Solomon, Thats right, looks server is dropping request sometimes and I am not sure how to find the issue here.I will add try-catch and let you know the result .thank you for your reply

Comment: Sounds good! Hopefully you can get it working. And no problem! I know these issues can be really frustrating, especially when it takes so long to reproduce an error.

Comment: Looks like it's worked , it's reading the webrequest again in catch and its success . I will keep them on observation for few more hours ,thank you - solomon bash

Comment: No Problem! @Prathvi